# Company of Heroes 2 Main Theme | What is the music here based off of and where do I find more music like this?

Tags: soundtrack, identify-this-genre

> "Animals flee this hell; the hardest stones cannot bear it for long; only man endures." – German officer at the Battle of Stalingrad

---

**YouTube Link**:--

[This song may be intense.]

(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9eKbJJ1I1Jg)

---

This is from the video game, *Company of Heroes 2*'s soundtrack. Where can I find music like this?

The video game is about the World War II Eastern Front, with the Soviet Forces facing Wehrmacht.

The music is composed by Cris Velasco.

---

**Question**:--

Is this music based off any genre, style, and/or type of music?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common musical style for soundtracks.  It is based on European classical music of the mid to late [Romantic period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romantic_music).

Charateristics according to Wikipedia:

> - The use of new or previously not so common musical structures like the song cycle, nocturne, concert etude, arabesque and rhapsody, alongside the traditional classical genres. Programme music became somewhat more common;
> - A greater emphasis on melody to sustain musical interest. The classical period often used short, even fragmentary, thematic material while the Romantic period tended to make greater use of longer, more fully defined and more satisfying themes;
> - The use of a wider range of dynamics, for example from ppp to fff, supported by large orchestration;

Romantic music was often programmatic (based around a narrative theme) so it's a natural for soundtracks, and it was one of the most lush, melodic and emotionally passionate periods in classical music.

The big difference in contemporary soundtrack music is that it often uses a mashup of the instrumental and choral styles, and uses a wide palette of elements that might have originally been favored by different composers or in separate longer works.  It also sometimes brings in more modern elements such as modern percussion, styles from global musical traditions, or rock-inspired progressions.

SIMILAR MUSIC

- Dvorak's [New World Symphony](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HClX2s8A9IE) is considered a classic of the late Romantic style.
- Grieg's famous [In the Hall of the Mountain King](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kLp_Hh6DKWc) is an obvious ancestor of modern soundtracks, given that it was composed to accompany a play.
- Faure's [Pavane](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jw8PurepHxk) is a beautiful and well-known late Romantic piece with similar orchestration (including a chorus), although it's less dark and epic.
- [The Gael](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9tjdswqGGVg) (Main Theme from *Last of the Mohicans*) is a Celtic-influenced late twentieth-century movie soundtrack song with a similar feel.