# Company of Heroes 2 - British Forces Theme | What is the music here based off of and where do I find more music like this?

Tags: soundtrack, identify-this-genre

(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ahr6APbE1Y)

This is from the video game, *Company of Heroes 2 - The British Forces*
 Expansion Pack/DLC's soundtrack. Where can I find music like this?

I have decided to post this as a separate question, because the style is completely different in nature from the "Main Theme"'s Operatic style. [The main theme can be find found in the link below.]

The main theme pertains to the Wehrmach's/Soviet Forces' theme and has a more militaristic and operatic style. What is the style for the British Forces, as supplied in the link above?

Is this particular piece of music based off any genre, style, and/or type of music?

[Related Question](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/8295/company-of-heroes-2-main-theme-what-is-the-music-here-based-off-of-and-where-d/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "World War II was won with British brains, American brawn, and Russian blood." ~ Attributed to Joseph Stalin

---

[**Sound Warning**: The links in this answer lead to unusually loud noise and music in the form of YouTube videos. This warning is for anyone in a situation sensitive to loud sound, such as wearing headphones or being at work.]

---

The soundtracks found in *Company of Heroes 2* are quite similar to the soundtracks of World War II films.

**This is the direct answer to your question**: *To find music similar to what the OP supplied, simply research the [soundtracks of World War II films](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_World_War_II_films).*

---

The [aforementioned soundtrack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ahr6APbE1Y) seems to be inspired by British World War II films that focused on the nation of Britain. The themes center around the survival of Britain and the "glory of the nation." Britain was not overthrown and survived, and thus this results in generic victory music.

This is reflected in the film *Battle of Britain* (1969 film).

---

The [Germans' theme](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9eKbJJ1I1Jg) in *Company of Heroes 2* had more "gloom and doom" because German-centered films focused on the destruction of Nazi Germany, overthrow of Adolf Hitler, and militaristic themes.  Simply put: Nazi Germany lost the war, and the music mirrors this.

This is reflected in *Downfall* (2004 film).

*Schindler's List* also has similar soundtrack.

---

The Soviets share the same theme and Nazi Germany, but there are other pieces of music that are inspired by the Soviet Union in the game.

The piece, ["O My Brother, Be Strong"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iCDViyWMQJY), is from the game, and this reflects the mood of the Soviet Union on the Eastern Front.

While the Soviet Union won the war, there was a great loss of life. The emphasis was on the corruption of the Soviet leaders, mass loss of life, self-sacrifice, pain and suffering, and yes, also victory and triumph.

- (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_II_casualties_of_the_Soviet_Union)
- (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_Anthem_of_the_Soviet_Union)

I'm not familiar with World War II films covering the Eastern Front and the Soviet Union; and Russian music.

---

The [American theme](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fo4SQMv8J9I) focused much more on struggles and heroism surrounding a small band of soldiers, sacrifice, and small-scale heroism.

This is inspired by the themes of movies such as *Saving Private Ryan* and  series such as *Band of Brothers* (miniseries).

---

**Closing**:--

This is a possible link of the title "Company of Heroes" to World War II films.

I'll close this piece of writing with a clip from *Band of Brothers*:--

[Consult [this guide](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0185906/parentalguide?ref_=tt_ql_stry_5) before watching the link directly above.]

Please consider supporting disabled veterans in any way you (realistically) can.

Answer (score 2):

This is like the generic kind of film music you'll find in a lot of modern movies e.g. "Lord of the Rings". The orchestration mostly corresponds to that of the late romantic period, but with later rhythmic elements. The beginning is an attempt to sound like the melody of a folk song without sounding like any particular song. The trumpet calls a bit later evoke a 'military' mood. And so it goes on.

If you want more of this kind of music (and better) try starting with Howard Shore's music for "Lord of the Rings", John Barry's music for "Dances with Wolves" or just about anything by John Williams.

And if you seriously want to delve into this kind of music start with Dmitri Shostakovich's Fifth Symphony

Comment: "This is like the generic kind of film music you'll find in a lot of modern movies ... " ~ PiedPiper John Williams, of Star Wars fame, was inspired by World War II films. That's where the term "Stormtrooper" in Star Wars comes from.  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stormtrooper_(Star_Wars)) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stormtrooper) (https://companyofheroes.fandom.com/wiki/Stormtroopers)

Comment: (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_of_Star_Wars) I'll leave it up to you, if you decide to include this information in your answer. Best wishes. :) :D